# Handling Automatic Naming of Files In C++ Sprintf

Tags: c++, file, char, printf

I am currently writing a program in C++. I want to save a number of files continuously throughout the run of my program. The format of the filename is as such:
char fnameC[sizeof "C:\..._SitTurn_104_c2_00_00_000.bmp"]; 
- SitTurn is an experiment name
- 104 is an experiment number

These two will be changing after each different run of the program. Currently, my program works like this:

```
char fnameCVS[sizeof"C:\\Users\\Adam\\Desktop\\Skeleton_RGBDepth_DataAcquisition2013\\Skeleton_RGBDepth_DataAcquisition2013\\Skeleton_SitTurn_104_c2_02.csv"];


LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
LARGE_INTEGER t1, t2;
double elapsedTime;

SYSTEMTIME comptime;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GetSystemTime(&comptime);
    sprintf_s(fnameCVS, "C:\\Users\\Adam\\Desktop\\Skeleton_RGBDepth_DataAcquisition2013\\Skeleton_RGBDepth_DataAcquisition2013\\Skeleton_SitTurn_104_c2_%02d.csv", comptime.wDay);
```

However, I tried this and I can't seem to get it to work. Can anyone help me?

```
...//rest of code set up
string expName = "SitStand";
string subjNumber = "101";

char fnameCVS[sizeof "C:\\Users\\Adam\\Desktop\\Skeleton_RGBDepth_DataAcquisition2013\\Skeleton_RGBDepth_DataAcquisition2013\\Skeleton_" + expName + "_" + subjNumber + "_c2_02.csv"];


LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
LARGE_INTEGER t1, t2;
double elapsedTime;

SYSTEMTIME comptime;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GetSystemTime(&comptime);
    sprintf_s(fnameCVS, "C:\\Users\\Adam\\Desktop\\Skeleton_RGBDepth_DataAcquisition2013\\Skeleton_RGBDepth_DataAcquisition2013\\Skeleton_" + expName + "_" + subjNumber + "_c2_%02d.csv", comptime.wDay);
```

Since I am using this filename later in the program also, I would like to be able to just rename all files by changing the two strings: expName and subjNumber. Can someone help me explain how I can name my files using a string inputs (e.g. expName and subjNumber), so I only have to rename those corresponding string each time I change the experiment name, or subject number. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the buffer size is correct (`sizeof "..." + string` == `sizeof(string)`?) Try: `char fnamecvs[1024];`, and also let `sprintf` to do all substitutions: `sprintf(fnamecvs, "C:\\...\\Skeleton_%s_%s_c2_%02d.csv", expName.c_str(), subjNumber.c_str(), comptime.wDay);`

Comment: Why are you using sprintf and C strings in a C++ program? I mean, do you have a reason for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
char fnameCVS[MAX_PATH+1];

SYSTEMTIME comptime;
GetSystemTime(&comptime);

sprintf_s(fnameCVS, _countof(fnameCVS), "C:\\Users\\Adam\\Desktop\\Skeleton_RGBDepth_DataAcquisition2013\\Skeleton_RGBDepth_DataAcquisition2013\\Skeleton_SitTurn_104_c2_%02d.csv", comptime.wDay);
```

Or this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::string expName = "SitStand";
std::string subjNumber = "101";
std::string fnameCVS;

SYSTEMTIME comptime;
GetSystemTime(&comptime);

std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "C:\\Users\\Adam\\Desktop\\Skeleton_RGBDepth_DataAcquisition2013\\Skeleton_RGBDepth_DataAcquisition2013\\Skeleton_" << expName << "_" << subjNumber << "_c2_" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << comptime.wDay << ".csv";

fnameCVS = oss.str();
```

Comment: Thanks! I believe the second option works nice, and it builds on Matt's answer too!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `sprintf` and `std::string`, which is never a good plan. You should either pick to use C's `sprintf` with `char *`, or C++'s `std::string` with `std::stringstream`.

Your `fnameCVS` array isn't going to be big enough: you'll take the `sizeof` of a `std::string`, which almost certainly will not be what you want.

Option 1: Use only `sprintf`. Allocate a big-enough string (e.g. `char fnameCVS[256]`) and use `snprintf(fnameCVS, 256, "...Skeleton_%s_%d_c2_%02.csv", ...)`.

Option 2: Use only `string` and use a `std::stringstream` to build your filename.

Comment: I used Option 1, but now my file isn't even being created. Right afterwards I have:

ostreame myfile;
myfile.open(fnameCVS, ios::app);

Answer (score 0):

This is a *really bad idea*:

```
char fnameCVS[sizeof"C:\\Users\\Adam\\Desktop\\Skeleton_RGBDepth_DataAcquisition2013\\Skeleton_RGBDepth_DataAcquisition2013\\Skeleton_SitTurn_104_c2_02.csv"];
```

The main reason is that it is very difficult to visually inspect whether you have allocated the right number of bytes. Perhaps you make a slight change to the filename later in the `sprintf` line but then you forget to update this line or you make a typo. Boom, buffer overflow (which may go undetected until it is time to give a presentation).

A secondary bug is that when you use `%02d` in printf, the `2` is a *minimum* field width; if the number would require more than 2 digits then it outputs more than 2 digits, causing a buffer overflow. To be safe here you'd need to check that the number is between 0 and 99 before printing it.

Finally, `sprintf_s` is a non-standard function, there's really no reason to use it instead of `sprintf` or `snprintf`.

In C++ the equivalent formatting is a bit more wordy, but leaves no possibility of buffer overflows:

```
std::string fnameCVS;

// ...

std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "C:\\Users\\whatever...." << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') 
    << comptime.wDay;
fnameCVS = oss.str();
```

If you really want to stick with the `printf` family plus a static char array (note: you can use printf and a dynamically-sized char container) then to make your code safe:

```
char const my_format[] = "C:\\Users\\whatever.....\\%02d.csv";
char fnameCVS[ sizeof my_format - 2 ];   // "NN" is two chars shorter than "%02d"

// ...
if ( comptime.wDay < 0 || comptime.wDay > 99 )
     throw std::runtime_error("wDay out of range");

snprintf(fnameCVS, sizeof fnameCVS, my_format, comptime.wDay);
```

Your update indicates that you want to compute various other parts of the filename at runtime too; the C++ version that I suggest is easier to extend than the C-with-static-array version where you have to calculate the amount of memory you need by hand.

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense. I guess for me, I knew the constraints of my naming conventions, so I didn't pay too much attn to the size of the buffer at first.